# Can't build MonoDevelop on an embedded Linux

Tags: linux, msbuild, mono, monodevelop, xbuild

Good day!

I'm trying to build MonoDevelop on/for an embedded/minimal Linux, and can't build msbuild from [source](https://github.com/mono/mono-addins/issues/141) which is why I'm using the binary from this [DEB package](http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/msbuild/msbuild_16.0+xamarinxplat.2018.09.26.17.53-0xamarin3+ubuntu1604b1_all.deb).
This basically works as it seems, but now make ends with an error:

[configure output](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/files/2946602/config.log)

[make output](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/files/2946604/make.log)

Can someone please help me to get MonoDevelop built?

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your build log:

> /update/download/monodevelop-7.8/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.csproj(146,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "bash build_libgit2.sh" exited with code
>   -1.
>       "/update/download/monodevelop-7.8/Main.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>       "/update/download/monodevelop-7.8/external/fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.FSharp.fsproj"
>   (default target) (81) ->
>       /update/download/monodevelop-7.8/external/fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.FSharp.fsproj(33,3):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "/update/swroot/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/FSharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

For the latter, did you install F#? (Just `apt-get install fsharp` should suffice.) And for the second, try running `bash build_libgit2.sh` separately to see the error message.

Comment: Yes, I had installed fsharp, but an old version from the Ubuntu repo. Now I have installed the DEB http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fsharp/fsharp_4.1.33-0xamarin7+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb as well as http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fsharp/libfsharp-core4.3-cil_4.1.33-0xamarin7+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb and added a symlink /usr/lib/mono -> /usr/local/lib/mono. This fixed all problems so far, except the build_libgit2.sh thing. Running in its directory, this is the output:
https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/files/2952061/monodevelop.log

Comment: Thank you for your answer, btw! :)

Comment: you shouldn't make those kind of symlinks; if you need that it means that should have installed in a different prefix

Comment: your call to `build_libgit2.sh` is highlighting a C compilation error: `/update/download/monodevelop-7.8/external/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c: In function 'bio_create':
/update/download/monodevelop-7.8/external/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c:36:3: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'BIO {aka struct bio_st}'
  b->init = 1;` you should post this as a new StackOverflow question

Comment: Looks like a version problem with OpenSSL 1.1.1. Can you confirm that <1.1.1 (1.0.2r) is required? Because I'm having terrible trouble getting this to work!

Comment: I don't think MonoDevelop developers dictate what version of OpenSSL is required, but libgit2 developers do. You're having trouble building a dependency of MonoDevelop, not MonoDevelop.

Comment: Shouldn't the --disable-git option to ./configure work around this problem? The configuration summary says "Git: no", but the problem still persists?

Comment: you are right, that might be a bug in the makefiles; you could try to look into it and submit a pull request

Comment: Wasn't able to change anything. Will file a bug now. Thank you for your help again! :)